# Liferay error org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mycompany.myapp.model.MyModel

Tags: hibernate, liferay, hibernate-mapping

I am using Liferay 6.2 GA5 Community Edition.

I created entities normally in my `service.xml`, run a Service Builder, and successfully generated all classes files.  I tried any CRUD operation in MyModel model and always get success result.

I have a Stored Procedure whose output list of records, a record represents MyModel.
Then I try to call that Stored Procedure like this:

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) PortalBeanLocatorUtil.locate("liferaySessionFactory");
Session session = null;
try {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery("{ CALL dbo.USP_GET_CHILD(:abc) }");
    query.addEntity("MyModel", MyModel.class).setString("abc", "aaa");
    List<MyModel> list = (List<MyModel>) query.list();
    _log.info("size: " + list.size());
    for (MyModel o : list) {
        _log.info("result: " + o.getFullName());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    _log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
}
```

From code above, I get error `org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.mandiri.ipsplus.model.MyModel` at line `query.list()`

I know it happened because I put `.addEntity("MyModel", MyModel.class)`,

but if I didn't do that I will always get `ClassCastCastException` at line `for (MyModel o : list)` because I was trying to cast Hibernate default model into MyModel.

After searching this kind of exception, I got some article in Hibernate-specific topics, that saying I must put `@Entity` annotation in MyModel. But in Liferay, model will always be generated from `service.xml`, right?

How to solve this problem? Is there any attribute in `service.xml` or any XML file configuration that can solve this?

thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you mixing ServiceBuilder-generated entities with raw hibernate access? I'd rather suggest that you either stay on the ServiceBuilder side (which mostly hides hibernate from you) or you go hibernate all the way and omit ServiceBuilder.

Within the context of Liferay (e.g. the need to cover applications deployed in several contexts) ServiceBuilder has its advantages: You can easily access your API in all plugins/portlets, no matter which web application they're deployed in.

Comment: thank you, I have removed `.addEntity()` method, and do a proper casting to the result of `query.list()` , now it's work